# Error en consulta a Base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo esta sentencia de PHP para un buscador con 3 parametros, todo me va bien pero cuando cuando llego a esta sentencia no me la ejecuta, creo que hay un error con los AND, pero no se que puede ser, se poco de base de datos, asi que pregunto por aca para su ayuda.

```
$resultado = $link->query("
            SELECT * 
            FROM producto 
            INNER JOIN bodega 
            ON producto.idBodega = bodega.idBodega
            INNER JOIN proveedor
            ON producto.idProveedores = proveedor.idProveedores 
            WHERE 
            producto.nombreProducto like '".$datos['string']."%' AND  
            producto.idBodega = ".$datos['bodega']." AND 
            producto.categoriaProducto = ".$datos['categoria']." AND 
            ORDER BY 
            producto.nombreProducto ASC 
        ");
```

Tengo esta sentencia de PHP para un buscador con 3 parametros, todo me va bien pero cuando cuando llego a esta sentencia no me la ejecuta, creo que hay un error con los AND, pero no se que puede ser, se poco de base de datos, asi que pregunto por aca para su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que es exactamente 'no me la ejecuta'? ¿Da algun error? ¿No devuelve nada?, etc...

Comment: Haber te explico, es un buscador con tres parametros, y el buscador funciona pero cuando ejecuto la consulta en caso en que el buscador tenga los tres parametros actitovos osea que se pasan las tres variables por php para buscar la relacion, entonces simplemente no me la ejecuta... dando null de resultado

Comment: El último AND (que está justo delante del ORDER BY) te sobra. Esto da un error y por eso no te la ejecuta.

Comment: Gracias @JoséDelgado Excelente algo tan simple pero que no vi :D

Comment: @JoséDelgado Como has hallado la solución sería bueno que la pusieras como respuesta y que Maiker te la aceptase, así como explicar el porque ese AND le sobra. De esta forma tu ganas REP, Maiker también y los siguientes usuarios podrán aprender de este error y solución. Un saludo ;D

Comment: @JoseManuelMorales tambien se le puede votar en el comentario, aunque no se si se sube la REP

Comment: @JoseManuelMorales ya está publicada la respuesta, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: @MaikerLeon te recomendaria que revisaras el codigo, ya que ese tipo de consultas pueden llegar a darte falsos resultados si no pasas algun parametro. Normalmente la query se construye como una cadena y vas añadiendo los `AND` necesarios en función de si se ha indicado filtro o o no.

Comment: @Jakala si, se le puede votar el comentario, pero lo adecuado es que toda pregunta tenga una respuesta aceptada, si la pregunta es aceptable y no la cierran por algún problema. De esta forma los usuarios que lleguen a ella desde los buscadores podrán ver, de manera sencilla, como se solucionó. Al menos así creo que es como debería ser. En cuanto al comentario, que yo sepa, votar no da REP, tampoco es que sea algo imperativo, pero mas que nada es por lo que dije antes del orden y la facilidad de encontrar soluciones. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error está en que el último `AND` que has puesto (justo antes del `ORDER BY`) es la causa del error. La palabra `AND` se utiliza como operador lógico y siempre tiene que ir entre dos predicados. En este caso, el intérprete se queda esperando el segundo predicado y no lo encuentra, por eso da error.

```
$resultado = $link->query("
            SELECT * 
            FROM producto 
            INNER JOIN bodega 
            ON producto.idBodega = bodega.idBodega
            INNER JOIN proveedor
            ON producto.idProveedores = proveedor.idProveedores 
            WHERE 
            producto.nombreProducto like '".$datos['string']."%' AND  
            producto.idBodega = ".$datos['bodega']." AND 
            producto.categoriaProducto = ".$datos['categoria']."
            ORDER BY 
            producto.nombreProducto ASC 
        ");
```